# What are the minimum requirements for .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: .net-4.0, installation, windows-server-2003, prerequisites

In the [Microsoft docs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements) it says that the .NET framework 4.0 requires SP2 on Windows Server 2003, but a colleague of mine has just installed on a non SP2 windows 2003 Server machine without any issue. Can someone verify whether SP2 is required or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements) is "Supported Operating Systems". Even though you might be able to install "without issues", or even apparently run an application, that doesn't mean things really work the way they should for every scenario/application that would normally. Your basically of to unsupported territory.

In case of problems you encounter, you will not know if it is due to not being officially supported, or something genuinely wrong.

If you care about that certainly depends, but for production applications, or anything that costs someone time or money.

I would not do it, in the long run doesn't seem worth the effort.